# 'If not' CSS Selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So this may be ambitious, but I'm trying to solve the following problem with CSS only:

```
.this-class[if-is-not-a-table], .this-class .something-else { 
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to find a way to use advanced CSS selectors to only apply a style dependent on whether or not it is NOT something else. Like apply this but only if it's not on a table element. Is this possible?

NOTE: Also, this is for IE 8, so if this can be backwards compatible at all that'd be amazing!

Comment: `:not(table)` should work.

Comment: Do be aware that `:not()` will not work in IE8 or lower, if older IE browser compatibility is a concern.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the [`:not()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation), but IE8 does not support it:

```
.this-class:not(table), .this-class .something-else { 
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Thankfully, getting it to work for IE8 is trivial — simply apply the style to any elements with `.this-class`, and override it for the ones that *are* tables instead:

```
.this-class, .this-class .something-else { 
    border: 1px solid red;
}

table.this-class {
    border: none;
}
```

Notice that the `.this-class .something-else` part of your first rule remains completely separate, matching descendants of `.this-class` regardless of what type of element it is. If that is intended, you can leave that portion unchanged. Otherwise, if you want the styles to apply to descendants of `.this-class` *with the same condition*, you will need to repeat the condition accordingly.

Using `:not()`:

```
.this-class:not(table), .this-class:not(table) .something-else { 
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

And using an override (for IE8):

```
.this-class, .this-class .something-else { 
    border: 1px solid red;
}

table.this-class, table.this-class .something-else {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

**[`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)** is what you're looking for:

In your case it's:

```
.this-class:not(table), .this-class .something-else {
```

As @ajp15243 noted, `:not()` isn't supported in IE8 and lower.

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK `:not` is not supported in IE8

The best I can offer is:

```
.this-class { 
    border: 1px solid red;
}
table.this-class {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, the value to use in `table.this-class` is basically what the value would otherwise be had it not been set in `.this-class`. This varies depending on the use case - it may not necessarily be the initial value of `border: 0 none`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `:not()` selector. In other words:

```
.this-class:not(table), .this-class .something-else { 
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

A generic example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5EuM/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:not` [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot).

```
.this-class:not(table) { border: 1px solid red }
```

[Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9DxsD/)